# Echo html tag inside PHP not working

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a php code and try to echo a some html tags but my code is not working it shows blank page. I forgot something?

Please check my code below Thankyou.

```
 <?php

      foreach($category_options_1 as $key=>$row)

      {

          if($row['option_type'] == 'DROPDOWN')

          {

              if($row['option_id'] == '20' && !empty($row['option_value'] == '0'))

              {


                  {



                      echo '<p class="bottom-border"><strong>'.$row['option_id'].':</strong><span>'. echo lang_check('Studio').'</span><br style="clear: both;" /></p>';
                      else

                        echo'<p class="bottom-border"><strong>'.$row['option_name'].':</strong> <span>'._che($row['option_value'].'</span><br style="clear: both;" /></p>';

                      endif;
                      endforeach;

                  }

              }

          }



      }

  ?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting to see what's wrong. And you can't mix control structure syntax like you are.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. **There are mixed `))` here instead of one: `if($row['option_id'] == '20' && !empty($row['option_value']) == '0')`.** And not only that. There are way too many mistakes in your code.

Comment: @Soolie Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @JohnConde thanks for reminder